# How do I use other React hooks inside a React useMemo hook function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was thinking of optimizing some code as the results can be cached since it only needs to iterate through the data once.  In my case it's determining the colors and font styles for a specific set of components for Native Base.

Presently I `useTheme()` to get the theme data.  So I thought I can simply go from

```
function useTextStyle(component: string) : TextStyle {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colorMode = useColorMode();
  return computeTextStyles(component, colorMode);
}
function useTextStyles() : StyleSheet.NamedStyle<{header1:TextStyle,body:TextStyle}> {
  return {
    header1: useTextStyle('Heading');
    body: useTextStyle('Text');
  }
}
```

to

```
function useTextStyles() {
  const colorMode = useColorMode();
  return useMemo(()=> ({
    header1: useTextStyle('Heading');
    body: useTextStyle('Text');
  }), [colorMode])
}
```

But that gives a warning saying I shouldn't use hooks in `useMemo`.

Comment: Did you know React Hook must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function?

Answer (score 1):

(Without being preachy I promise) I would first ask whether this is a **needed** adjustment - unless theres a noticeable performance dip I wouldn't bother. Ultimately none of this should change unless the `colorMode` is changing by the looks of things, and it can be a bad thing when things are being over-optimised (useMemo does have a cost associated with calling it, which may or may not outweigh the benefit of the memoization). Best to use the chrome debugger to see if it actually changes things after, if not faster then it's probably best left unoptimised for the sake of the next develop trying to figure out whats going on).

However! If you deem it is necessary, then the problem is in the `useTextStyle` within the memo portion.

I would personally be more inclined to write it as:

```
function useTextStyles() : StyleSheet.NamedStyle<{header1:TextStyle,body:TextStyle}> {
  // const theme = useTheme(); // Is this even used?
  const colorMode = useColorMode();

  return useMemo(()=> ({
    header1: computeTextStyles('Heading', colorMode);
    body: computeTextStyles('Body', colorMode);
  }), [colorMode])
}
```

Either way you still need to call the compute functions on all of the entries, and this way you are only just calling the `useColorMode` once and passing the value along, and the only dependency is to be the `colorMode`, (and computeTextStyle)

Comment: It's more of a general thing I may not be doing it for this context in the future, it was just the simplest use case I can think of.  However, your answer matches what I did in the end which was to refactor useTextStyle to use a common function.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I wanted to make it clear that it shouldn't be overused as depending on experience level this can be a common source of problems. If you feel the answers adequately complete feel free to accept the answer. Either way have a nice day!